# REST Post from PHP to Java

Tags: java, php, spring, rest

I have a REST Spring Java service that works perfectly with Java client, but cannot get it work with PHP client. Im new to PHP and have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/add_something")
@ResponseBody
public SomeDTO save_something(@Valid @RequestBody SomeDTO someDTO) {

    return someService.save(someDTO);
}
```

SomeDTO:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "someDTO")
public class SomeDTO {

    private String  name;
    private CustomSome customSome;

    ...
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "customDTO")
public class CustomDTO {

    private String name;
    ...
}
```

And PHP client call:

```
$data = json_encode(array('someDTO'  => array(
               'name' => set_value('name'),
               'customSome' => array('name' => set_value('custom_name'))
                                             )
                         )
                   );

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
                CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                        'Content-Type: application/json',
                        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)
                ),
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data
        ));

        // Send the request
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

It doesnt reach the controller method. Similar controller method without RequestBody is reached. But once json is required to be sent, nothing happens.

Comment: Do you get a HTTP status code of 416 or 415 when you try the PHP code?

Comment: I get Bad Syntax 400.

Comment: @user1335163 try this: $ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
 $response = curl_exec($ch);